# How to specify .env file variable based on an external file with docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

Like the title says, I would like to have a specific variable in my `.env` file take on a value specified in an external text file with docker. For example, let's say I have a `docker-compose.yml` file that looks like this:

```
services:
    someService:
        env_file:
        - .env
```

And in that `.env` file, I have a variable defined like this:

```
SOME_VARIABLE=A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H
```

I am wondering if there is  some way to define `A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H` in a file called, say, `vars.txt` like this:

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
```

and have my `SOME_VARIABLE` equal everything in `vars.txt`, using the newline as  a delimiter to store comma separated values `A, B, C, D, E, F ,G`?

Comment: Can you talk more about your use case?

Answer (score 0):

I use this configuration:
[Docker guide](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env_file-configuration-option)

```
version: '3.1'
services:

  celery:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-celery
    container_name: cronjobs
    restart: always
    environment:
      TZ: GMT
```

> ```
>     env_file:
>     - ./variables.env
> ```

```
    tty: true
```

I created a variables.env file and then add to my docker-compose.yml file this lines:

```
env_file:
- ./variables.env
```

The content of my file variables.env is:

```
C_FORCE_ROOT=1
TEST=TEST
MYENV=MY ENV
```

Then i recreate my container and i accesed it  by bash and tested if my env variables and it was  created:

```
# printenv
HOSTNAME=979980b0d05b
PYTHON_PIP_VERSION=9.0.1
HOME=/root
GPG_KEY=97FC712E4C024BBEA48A61ED3A5CA953F73C700D
TERM=xterm
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
LANG=C.UTF-8
CELERY_VERSION=3.1.25
```

> ```
> TEST=TEST
> ```

```
PYTHON_VERSION=3.5.3
```

> C_FORCE_ROOT=1

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL=amqp://guest@rabbit
```

> ```
> MYENV=MY ENV
> ```

```
PWD=/home/user
TZ=GMT
```